# Search only on alphanumeric chars of a column

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a table column of type nvarchar.
As an example, lets say one of the records is `A320 - Airbus`. 
Contains both alphanumerics and a hyphen in this case.

When I search for `320A`, the search should pick it up by ignoring the 2 whitespaces and a hyphen between the 2 words.

Currently, I can achieve this by doing this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name 
FROM Entity
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, ' ', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%320A%';
```

But if I have to add more escape chars, I have to keep applying `REPLACE` for every new escape char.

Would be good if I could do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM Entity
WHERE REGEXP(Name, '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$') LIKE '%320A%';
```

Comment: Sounds like a potential XY problem ;) Have you considered adding a 'search' column into your table and populate that without any undesired characters, e.g. name:`A320 - Airbus`, search:`A320AIRBUS`

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean by potential XY problem? The thought of creating a new column occurred but wondering if there's a simpler solution. Especially since databases are powerful at search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works

```
     SELECT DISTINCT replace(replace(replace(replace(Name,' ',''),'(',''),')',''),'-','') 
     as Name
     FROM Entity where 
     Name RLIKE '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$';
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a pretty workaround but it is a workaround.

Ii is easy if you know where your search string would be cut:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name 
FROM Entity
WHERE Name REGEXP '320[^a-zA-Z0-9]*A'
```

but if you don't know you should add the regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` between every character. It's kinda silly, but it works.